# yarn create react-app not working and aborting installation

Tags: reactjs, redux, yarnpkg, yarnpkg-v2, yarn-lock.json

I tried installing a react-app using yarn and got this error message:

> yarn version: 1.22.17
>
> npm version: 8.3.0

It is also showing an error of "No Lockfile found".

```
$ yarn create react-app redux-shopping-app
yarn create v1.22.17
[1/4] Resolving packages...
[2/4] Fetching packages...
[3/4] Linking dependencies...
[4/4] Building fresh packages...
success Installed "create-react-app@5.0.0" with binaries:
      - create-react-app

Creating a new React app in E:\Workspace\Scaler Development\06 React\redux-shopping-app.

Installing packages. This might take a couple of minutes.
Installing react, react-dom, and react-scripts with cra-template...

yarn add v1.22.17
info No lockfile found.
[1/4] Resolving packages...
warning react-scripts > @svgr/webpack > @svgr/plugin-svgo > svgo@1.3.2: This SVGO version is no longer supported. Upgrade to v2.x.x.
[2/4] Fetching packages...
error eslint@8.5.0: The engine "node" is incompatible with this module. Expected version "^12.22.0 || ^14.17.0 || >=16.0.0". Got "14.16.0"
error Found incompatible module.
info Visit https://yarnpkg.com/en/docs/cli/add for documentation about this command.

Aborting installation.
  yarnpkg add --exact react react-dom react-scripts cra-template --cwd E:\Workspace\Scaler Development\06 React\redux-shopping-app has failed.        

Deleting generated file... package.json
Deleting redux-shopping-app/ from E:\Workspace\Scaler Development\06 React
Done.
error Command failed.
Exit code: 1
Command: C:\Users\abc\AppData\Local\Yarn\bin\create-react-app
Arguments: redux-shopping-app
Directory: E:\Workspace\Scaler Development\06 React
Output:

info Visit https://yarnpkg.com/en/docs/cli/create for documentation about this command.
```

Comment: npx create-react-app my-app

Comment: Why is this question tagged `react-native`?

Comment: Change your directory names to non-space ones. 'Scaler_Development\06_React'. I stopped using space-including folder names after facing so=imilar issues